# To check whether an integer is a palindrome in O(1) space(Wrong answer)

Tags: c++, c

I tried solving this question by reversing the number ,using bitwise operations:- say for example if the number's binary representation is 00000110 ,what this code does is, send 0000011 into the code and then left shift reverse_num 5 times to get 01100000, which obviously is reverse of original,after that this program does an "&" of this number with original number.if answer is 1 ,then number is said as palindrome else false is returned.Is there some flaw in the logic? If there is ,I think it's in the & part.

```
class Solution {
public:
    bool isPalindrome(int x) {
        if(x<0)
            return false;
        int num=x;
        int reverse_num=x;
        int count=sizeof(x);
        num >>= 1;
        while(num)
            {
                reverse_num <<= 1;      
                reverse_num |= num & 1;
                num >>= 1;
                count--;
            }
        reverse_num <<= count;

        if(!(reverse_num&x))
            return true;
        else return false;
    }
};
```

I still want to know what is wrong with the previous code . Sorry for asking such a silly question .I am a noob in programming. The original question is here:https://oj.leetcode.com/problems/palindrome-number/

Although I was able to get around this question by doing this:

```
class Solution {
public:
    bool isPalindrome(int x) {
        long long y=0;
        long long t=x;
        long long p;
        p=x;
        while(t){
            y=y*10+t%10;
            t=t/10;
        }
        if(p==y && p>=0)
            return true;
        else return false;

    }

};
```

Comment: If you're asking what I think you're asking, in binary `10001` is a palindrome, but in decimal `17` is not.

Comment: `reverse_num & x` will be true if they have any bits in common, not all the bits. Use `reverse_num == x` to see if they're the same.

Comment: Bit reversal is not the same as digit reversal.

Comment: Reading the question on the site, your solution involves using extra space (which is not allowed) which may be why it is being rejected.  Otherwise I would suggest just putting each decimal into an array and reversing the array.

Comment: Allright I got the point.I was confusing bit reversal with digit reversal . So thanks everyone.

Comment: Should I remove this question or let it be,as it was a silly doubt?

Comment: BTW: recommend using `unsigned` rather than `int` to avoid sign bit complications.

Comment: @swapedoc: either clarify the question so it can be answered (or maybe it was already), or delete it.

Answer (score 0):

For the final if statement, && is the logical and. In C/C++ (and many other languages), a logical test on an integer will return true unless the value is 0.

So your function will only return true if either x or reverse_num is 0

Comment: I am sorry ,that was unintentional, I meant & only. but I got the point I was doing bit reversal but they want digit reversal which are different things